# Leibniz-Newton fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:$ $\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R $ be a differentiable function with continuous partial derivatives and with $f(0,0)=0$. Prove that there exist continuous function $g_1,g_2:$ $\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R $ such that
$f(x,y)=xg_1(x,y)+yg_2(x,y)$

I looked at the solution of this problem, and it was like this:
Using the Leibniz-Newton fundamental theorem of calculus, we can write 
$f(x,y)-f(0,0)=$\begin{aligned}\int_0^x\frac{ \partial f(s,0)}{\partial x}\,ds\  +\int_0^y\frac{ \partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\,dt \end{aligned}
I don't know how this equation came from Leibniz-Newton fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

For given $(x,y)$ consider the auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=f(t x,ty)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
Then
$$f(x,y)=\phi(1)-\phi(0)=\int_0^1\phi'(t)\>dt=\int_0^1\bigl(x f_{.1}(tx,ty)+y f_{.2}(tx,ty)\bigr)\>dt\ .$$
Therefore$$g_1(x,y):=\int_0^1f_{.1}(tx,ty)\>dt,\qquad g_2(x,y):=\int_0^1 f_{.2}(tx,ty)\>dt$$
will do the job.